# jQuery isotope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I've added jQuery isotope into my website. Page seems to work fine in Chrome, but in firefox it shows 2 columns, leaving wierd blank space in third column. You can check the page with problem at this link:
http://demo.webdezyner.com/flatshop/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/living-room/id/22/

I've included jQuery and isotope js file, and have added this code in the page under script tag:

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        var $container = jQuery('.products-grid');
        $container.isotope({
          duration: 250,
          itemSelector: '.item',
          resizable: true,
          layoutMode : 'fitRows'
        });
    });
```

I've tried changing attributes in css files, but to no avail. Please help me locate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine in my firefox browser.

Im running Firefox version 27.0

Have you looked at the debugging console in firefox? Any errors?

Comment: My version is 27.0.1. No errors shown in firebug console.

Comment: It is the dresses in the middle right?
Im not having any issues. I have three nice columns and if I resize the screen to a lesser size it changes nicely to two columns. Im seeing the same behaviour in firefox and chrome

Comment: It shows dresses in 2 columns, whereas actually it should be 3 columns.

Comment: One thing which i noticed, when the page is loading, the dress boxes appear to make nice 3 columns, and the sidebar shows correct accordians under 'Select Category' heading, but as soon as page completes its loading, they both mess up. Isotope showing 2 columns instead of 3, and accordian stops working altogether. Do you think these problems could be inter-related.